# Error: useState value from my child component is not changing right away that you need to press submit button twice

Tags: reactjs

I have data coming from my child component that needs to be passed on to the parent component. But my problem is I need to press the submit button twice. I tried to use the arrow function because I know this will update the state right away but not working. I tried to console.log the state inside useEffect and I see the changes. But when submit the state the the data is not appearing.

**Child Component**

```
const UploadFile = ({
  uploadeditemListFile,
  callChildFunction,
}) => {
  const [list, setList] = useState(isList);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [itemListFile, setItemListFile] = useState([]);

    const handleOnFileUpload = (e) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let i = 0; i < itemListFile.length; i++) {
      formData.append('uploadCollection', itemListFile[i]);
    }
    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `http://localhost:5000/api/seller/upload/${restaurantName}/${folderName}`,
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    }).then((res) => {
      uploadeditemListFile(res.data);
    });
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    handleOnFileUpload();
  }, [callChildFunction]);

  return (
    <>
HTML
    </>
  );
};
```

**Parent Component**

```
const RegisterSellerPage = ({ history }) => {
  const [accountInfo, setAccountInfo] = useState({
    restaurantName: '',
    businessType: '',
    costForOne: '',
    fullname: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
    email: '',
    mobileno: '',
    address: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userCurrentLocation')) || '',
    uploads: [],
  });
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [callChildFunction, setCallChildFunction] = useState(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  const handleOnSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCallChildFunction(true);
    dispatch(registerSellerAccount(accountInfo)); 
  };

  useEffect(() => {
console.log(accountInfo.uploads) 
  }, [accountInfo.imgUrl, history]);

  return (
    <FormContainer>
      <form noValidate onSubmit={handleOnSubmit} className='w-10/12 mx-auto'>
        <div className='form-group w-full relative'>
          <UploadFile
            restaurantName={accountInfo.restaurantName}
            folderName='menu'
            name='uploadCollection'
            accept='image/*'
            multiple={true}
            caption='Select a file'
            isList={true}
            uploadeditemListFile={(uploadeditemListFile) =>
              setAccountInfo({ ...accountInfo, uploads: uploadeditemListFile }) <-- props
            }
            callChildFunction={callChildFunction}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </FormContainer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing async await and promises which might be causing your issue. Its not obvious but await always operates on the final value returned by the statements its awaiting. This means you are actually using await on the result of .then instead of the axios invocation.  This may matter if an exception is thrown by the axios call.

```
const res = await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `http://localhost:5000/api/seller/upload/${restaurantName}/${folderName}`,
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
uploadeditemListFile(res.data);
```

Comment: Sir, the result of .then is not undefined and i tried your solution but nothing happen.

Comment: Ah, yeah I confused myself because .then obviously returns a promise. You still shouldn't mix the two.

Comment: Noted, I already modify the code but still, the problem is the same?

Comment: haha you have structured things in an insane way. You should not be invoking child component functions by changing component properties. Did you ever debug anything and even figure out if handleOnFileUpload  is only invoked once like you claim?